# Hidden redirect of / to subfolder using .htaccess in TYPO3

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, typo3

We're setting up a TYPO3 installation, and if the user calls **example.com/** we'd like the server to redirect to **/typo/index.php?id=106**.

This should happen without a change in the address bar. Every other file access on the server (for example example.com/test.png) should be redirected to example.com/typo/test.png).

This is the .htaccess file in the root directory. As I understand, it will redirect everything which doesn't have **/typo** in the URL to the subfolder and attach the parameters:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/typo/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ typo/$1 [L]
```

Now, this already seems to work, when I call example.com/index.php?id=106 I'm not getting a 404. Unfortunately TYPO3 seems to have some trouble (or the .htaccess configuration isn't correct), because we get a message saying "No input file specified".

What's also missing is the initial redirect when no path is specified. It should then go to /typo/index.php?id=106.

Answer (score 8):

You may try this in one .htaccess file in root directory:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# URL with no path
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/?$        [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule .*  /typo/index.php?id=106  [NC,L]

# URL with path    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/typo     [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)  /typo/$1             [NC,L]
```

Maps silently:

`http://domain.com/` to

`http://domain.com/typo/index.php?id=106`

and

`http://domain.com/anything`

`http://domain.com/typo/anything`

For permanent redirection, replace [NC,L] with [R=301,NC,L]

Comment: We'll try it out :) Will let you know what happens.

Comment: That looks like another option not in my answer: When the request is like this `http://domain.com/index.php?id=999` it would silently map to `http://domain.com/typo/index.php?id=999`? Do the other options in my answer work as expected?

Comment: I think you edited the comment and I didn't see the update. When the request is `http://domain.com/` it goes to `http://domain.com/typo/index.php?id=106` and it does NOT modify the request URL in the browser's address bar. Hence the [NC,L] flags. To **see** the redirected URL, flags `R` or `R=301` must be used.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I hit enter hoping it would create a new line. Instead it posted the comment, I then had to edit it. Well, it does actually redirect to 106, but it was not hidden. Gonna try again, maybe I did something wrong.